# Unable to destroy session using Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Noob here building my first Rails 4.0 app using Devise. Set up my controller and routes using the standard Devise tactics.

Rake Routes shows:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
```

In my Nav, my code is:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

I'm running the Guard gem so my server is always on, so I know it's not a mismatch b/w my routes and the server. I still get the following error:

> No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_out"

Any suggestions? Thanks all!

Comment: Guard won't pick up new changes if you've added a gem like devise since you started it. Have you restarted Guard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the `method` (http verb) option to `delete`:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: In that case, you should accept the answer, upvote is also useful for the community. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Check in config/initializers/devise.rb and make sure this is set:

`config.sign_out_via = :delete`

Also, in the view I have this and works just fine:

`<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %>`